# Using Page Hits for Segmentation in Adobe CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem

I am trying to set up personalised content in CQ5 using segmentation. When I use the out of the box "Page Hits" option it doesn't work. Is there some extra configuration I have to do to use Page Hits?

I've set up two segments applied to two teaser pages. For the first one I've used 
number of page hits is less than 4.
For the second I've used number of page hist is greater than 3.

Note, the teasers show up when I use Referral Keywords to test so I think the rest of the configuration is correct.

Can anyone give some advice about how to get the Page Hits segmentations to work?

Comment: Are you trying to use page hits on a per user basis?  The out of the box page hits component works on total page hits for that page as tracked by the impressions column in the site admin view.  It's pretty narrow in what it can be used for.  It isn't often you'll want to show something until the page becomes popular (>50 hits or whatever count you use).

Comment: @winkle Thanks for clearing that up. Is there a way for me to set up segmentation based on the amount of times a user has been to a page? Even if they are anonymous (e.g. via cookies)? I'm struggling to find good examples/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has this same problem, I solved it by using a session store and set a cookie on the users browser to record how many times they had been to a particular page. Using that, I was able to configure my segments and personalise areas of the page based on number of visits the user had made to that page.

Code for the session store:

```
//Create the session store

if (!CQ_Analytics.MyStore) {
    CQ_Analytics.MyStore = new CQ_Analytics.PersistedSessionStore();
    CQ_Analytics.MyStore.STOREKEY = "MYSTORE";
    CQ_Analytics.MyStore.STORENAME = "myclientstore";
    CQ_Analytics.MyStore.data={};

    CQ_Analytics.MyStore.findPageName = function(){
        var locationName = location.pathname;
        var n = location.pathname.indexOf("html");
        if(n !== -1){
            locationName = locationName.split('.')[0];
        }
        return locationName.split("/").slice(-1);
    }

    CQ_Analytics.MyStore.title = CQ_Analytics.MyStore.findPageName() + "-pageviews";

    CQ_Analytics.MyStore.loadData = function(pageViewed) {
        CQ_Analytics.MyStore.data = {"pageviewed":pageViewed};
    }

    CQ_Analytics.MyStore.getCookie = function(cname) {
        console.log("getting the cookie");
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0){
                console.log("return value for cookie is " + c.substring(name.length,c.length) );
                return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    CQ_Analytics.MyStore.setCookie = function(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        console.log("setting the cookie");
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

     CQ_Analytics.MyStore.checkCookie = function() {
        console.log("checking for cookie");
        var pViewd = CQ_Analytics.MyStore.getCookie(CQ_Analytics.MyStore.title);

        if (pViewd != "") {
            console.log("cookie is found and Viewed is " + pViewd);
            pViewd = parseInt(pViewd) + 1;
            CQ_Analytics.MyStore.setCookie(CQ_Analytics.MyStore.title, pViewd, 365);
            CQ_Analytics.MyStore.loadData(pViewd.toString());

        } else {
            if (pViewd === "" || pViewd === null) {
                console.log("cookie not found");
                CQ_Analytics.MyStore.setCookie(CQ_Analytics.MyStore.title, "1", 365);
                CQ_Analytics.MyStore.loadData("1");
            }
        }
    }

     CQ_Analytics.MyStore.checkCookie();

}
//register the session store
if (CQ_Analytics.CCM){

    CQ_Analytics.CCM.register(CQ_Analytics.MyStore)
}
```

The most useful documentation I found was this: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/client_context_detail.html#par_title_34